# Running multiple operations on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

On our website it is possible for our moderators to review content that people have posted. This goes with videos as well, although the video needs to be converted first. This either happens at night automatically (through a windows service) or sooner when a moderator starts it manually.

Now, this last part is where my question comes from. At first I thought I'd just write a separate service to handle the conversion. Whenever a moderator start the conversion a record is updated in the database to flag it for single conversion. Then the service will handle the rest. This all works great when it is just the one file.

But imagine this situation, moderator #1 starts the service. The service runs and starts a conversion of the file. During that process moderator #2 starts the conversion of a different file. It will try to start the service but fail because it is already started. The file will be flagged for individual conversion but will not convert as it could not start the service.

Now I'm searching for new ideas to work this out.

1. Is it possible to run multiple instances of one service?
2. Can I make the service more dynamic? For example if moderator #2 start the conversion it will start the service, but if the service is already starting, is it possible to add the file to the list? (At the start of the service I create a list which reads every file from the database looking for the individual conversion flag)
3. I know I've been thinking essentially on the service, is there another way to handle operations on the server that can handle multiple requests by moderators?

I realize it may sound a bit foggy, so please, if you have any questions just ask.

**EDIT:** Maybe I should provide some extra information, currently I'm a student working on a internship, my promoters did not really want for a file to be converted almost instantly. They wanted to have the conversion happen at night, unless a moderator manually starts it for a single file. Also, the website and the filesystem are on the same server (the database on a separate server). Basically the work will be done on the same server as the website is running on (it currently can't be separated). They are worried about the performance on the server.

Any comment will be appreciated!
Kinds Regards,
Floris

Comment: I would be surprised if asp.net doesn't have support for some kind of work queue. You make a fixed number of worker threads (maybe 1 in your case) that do a unit of work, then keep checking for new work to do until something appears.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on your particular requirements, but have you considered multi-threading and Thread Pools?

Comment: what if the service was always running and simply looked at a table ordered by a request timestamp (a simple queue)?  So, it would periodically query this queue table and process the items in order - it could even send the work out to multiple threads.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Bwawok and xman: I'm kind of unfamiliar on that area but I am willing to look into it. This would mean I'd have to abandon the service idea I guess. Could you perhaps provide some link where I could learn more of it? Or is there enough to find on msdn or google?

@Ryan: This could work but to do that I would need to run the service all the time, is this correct?

Comment: @Ryan: forget my last comment, you already said it was constantly running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO the sane way to handle this is with any form of queue. A simple database table (or a redis list) would suffice. Your service should simply check: is there work to do? I'd so: do it, otherwise sleep for a short period and re-query. As an optional extra, something like pub/sub could be used for faster wake-up so there is no perceptible delay between enqueue and dequeue - but ideally the queue/poll loop should work without this extra.

Then, the batch process is simply: add the work to the queue. Optionally, you might allow priority, such that a moderator (or other "live" user) gets work ahead of background processing.

It *is* possible to run the same exe as a service multiple times (giving it different service names), but each requires explicit setup. To be honest, it isn't worth it in your scenario : a simpler option would be to have more than one worker thread servicing the queue, which can be done within a single process.

Comment: So basicly I just update the datatable with a timestamp (when it has been requested) and let a service run and check if the datatable on a timed interval. In other words the service "runs" all the time, but will sleep when it has no work. If a service runs all the time, will it drain much on the servers performance?

Comment: @Floris virtually none at all. Next time you are in task manager, enable "show tasks by all users" and see how many things are silently doing nothing. Just make sure you use passive waiting (I.e. Either Thread.Sleep, a Timer, or a wait-handle), not active waiting (`while (DateTime.Now < nextRun) {} // very bad`)

Comment: If you do go with a queue, I would suggest using a persistent queue. Either a database managed queue you create, or use an existing one like MSMQ (built into Windows) or [Rhino Queues](http://ayende.com/blog/3480/rhino-queues), etc.

Comment: @hemp - just realised that was ambiguous - absolutely yes it should be persistent. I meant to say database table. Although I like redis at the moment, so for my own code I'd probably use a redis list. That also gets me the pub/sub for free :)

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the option for the Moderator to start the service manually (just my preference) and start a thread that polls your Database for files that need to be converted.

If you have the code that's in the service, you could run it within the function below.  If not, then keep the function below a single thread and programatically start the service within this function to perform the conversion.  The answer to this question can change drastically depending on whether or not you have the code for the service and can make changes.  You could put this same type of logic within the service if you can modify it.

In your Global.asax.cs's Application_Start event, I would start a new Thread that continuously loops and checks your database

```
using System.Threading;


   void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)        
   {
        Thread VideoConversionThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(VideoConversion));
        VideoConversionThread.Name = "VideoConversion";
        VideoConversionThread.IsBackground = true;
        VideoConversionThread.Start();
    }
    private void VideoConversion()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //Get Count of records that need conversion.
            if(Count > 0)
            {
                 var records = //GetRecords from database that require conversion
                 foreach(var record in records)
                 {
                     //either spawn a seperate worker thread for each record or perform tasks here

                     //perform conversion
                     //update database to mark item as completed
                     // or 
                     //in this single thread, you could also start the service
                     //(does the service Stop when it's finished?) 
                     //(if so, you can monitor and wait for it to be stopped for each record)
                 }
             }
             Thread.Sleep(5000); //sleep
         }
      }
```

Comment: Do you mean removing the option for manually starting a conversion for the moderators? If so you mean that every video will be updated some time after it has been uploaded the same day.

If each video will updated some time after the upload it might drain on the servers performance. Or am I getting it wrong here?

Your situation might work if I'd still keep the option for moderators to manually start the conversion (but just let them update the database with a request and let it check through your method).

Comment: Well, the idea would be that this process constantly converts files, removing the need for manual conversion requests.  I understand what you're saying though.  In the case that you just want to be able to handle multiple manual requests, the same type of logic would work, you would just need to have a table that kept track of the files that were manually requested for conversion.  Then, the process should loop through and run for each file.

Comment: Indeed, the same logic would work. It will be a matter of convincing my promotors to do it like this. As long as it doesn't drain on the websites performance when the code ain't running (sleeping).

Comment: A sleep will chew up any CPU, but the idea is to have the sleep only pause for a short while before starting the loop over (this way the datbase is checked frequently).  The database check will take a *little* cpu, which is why I first have a check in there for the COUNT of records, which should be a very quick and painless query.  It all depends on your database/hardware, but I can't imagine a loop checking the record count would do more than 1% cpu every few seconds.  You can test this real quick by writing a test application to poll the database and count records every few seconds...